# What is the best algorithm for predicting rare events?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, svm, random-forest, rare-events

I heard somewhere that logistic regression is a good candidate for this, but it doesn't work really well for me. Instead, Random Forests proved to be very efficient in my observed population.

The [Microsoft Azure Machine Learning Algorithm Cheat Sheet](http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/6/1/A613E11E-8F9C-424A-B99D-65344785C288/microsoft-machine-learning-algorithm-cheat-sheet-v2.pdf) says that we should use One-class SVM (or PCA-based anomaly) for binary cases.

What is the best algorithm? Or is there no explicit response to this type of question, and it depends on the data set?

Comment: It really puzzled me why this question can be closed by all the statistical experts, but none is an expert in the area of Machine Learning or Tensorflow.   I am no experts in any field, but in Tensorflow there is an example specifically to handle this issue, which exactly answer the OP question:

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/learning_to_remember_rare_events

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, this depends entirely on your data.

If you have little data, then logistic regression may be the best you can do (since you don't have enough data to detect interaction and similar effects). If you have a lot of data, I personally would rather look at a Random Forest, which should find interactions, nonlinearities etc.

However, if the underlying data generating process is actually rather simple, then a logistic regression may be more parsimonious and better in predicting than an RF, even for a large dataset. The problem is that you don't know in advance what the DGP is (because if you knew, you wouldn't be modeling).

So: it all depends on the data.

Finally, combining classifiers often improves accuracy over single classifiers, even over the most accurate single ones. So think about combining logistical regression, RFs, SVM and so forth and see whether that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, combining different models to construct the overall model seems to be a good idea. Do you have any document, or explaination on how to do this? I imagine that we simply take the weighted average of the predicted probabilities, is that true?

Comment: There are various ways of combining classifiers. Averaging probabilities is one. (If you have reasonable weights, these *can* improve matters, but unweighted averaging is often already pretty helpful.) You could also let your classifiers "vote" in some way, although majority voting may not be useful for *rare* events - maybe you could classify a data point as an event if $k$ out of $n$ classifiers vote for it, with $k$ optimized in some way.